# Read history of a task on a remote server

Tags: c#, windows-server-2008, scheduled-tasks

I want to access the history of task on a remote server. I tried this [library](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Documentation) and got stuck at the point, where I access the history. At the moment only the scheduled tasks are printed, but I would like to print their history as well. Does someone has an idea what is wrong?

I'm a little concerned about the t.path variable because it looks like this "\taskname". Could this be the problem?

```
namespace Inbox_Workflow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TaskService ts = new TaskService("\\server", "user", "abc", "abc");
            EnumAllTasks(ts);
            Console.ReadKey(true)
        }

        static void EnumAllTasks(TaskService ts)
        {
                EnumFolderTasks(ts.RootFolder);
        }

        static void EnumFolderTasks(TaskFolder fld)
        {
            foreach (Task task in fld.Tasks)
                ActOnTask(task);
        }

       static void ActOnTask(Task t)
        {
            Console.Write(t+" \n");
            TaskEventLog log = new TaskEventLog(t.Path);
            foreach (TaskEvent item in log)
                Console.Write(item + " \n");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: did you manage to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, the \taskname is just fine, in fact it's required (it's the path).

You're having the same issue I was having until I re-read the [docs](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples#history)

> If you use the TaskEventLog constructor which specifies a remote
>   machine, you will need to use impersonation to logon to an account
>   with privileges to the remote machine before instantiating the
>   TaskEventLog.

So, Change your ActOnTask from this

```
TaskEventLog log = new TaskEventLog(t.Path);
```

To This:

```
TaskEventLog log = new TaskEventLog("server", t.Path, "Domain", "UserName", "Password");
```

And you should be good to go.